# PHP/MYSQL query no result, encoding wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

i have a strange problem bugging me for some time now and i am unable to resolve it.
For testing purposes i create a URL with a parameter which is used to get a result from the database. It works fine most of the time, but it seems to struggle with special characters, like the "ß".

Here is an example URL where the user is urlencoded:

https://www.testurl.com/login.php?user=bu%DFmann (bu%DFmann = bußmann)

And this is a part of my php script:

```
$user = new User;
$loginOrEmail = $this->_helper->get_request_value("user", array("get"));
if ($user->check_user_is_valid($loginOrEmail)) {
.........
```

This is the `check_user_is_valid` method:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($loginOrEmail) . "' OR login='" . mysql_real_escape_string($loginOrEmail) . "') AND activated = 'yes'";
$result = $database->query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Now this seems to return false for the url above. If i print the query (with print_r or var_dump) the query looks fine:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email='bußmann' OR login='bußmann') AND activated = 'yes'
```

In fact. If i copy and paste this query to phpMyAdmin and execute it, it yields the row i was expecting.
What is going on here? Where is the problem? I am pretty sure it has something to do with wrong encoding or something, because it works for all other names.

I already have `mysql_set_charset('utf-8', $connection);` after i connect to the database.

Please NOTE: I am aware that this is neither secure nor the best way to go. It is just for testing purposes.

Comment: The syntax is `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);` and not `mysql_set_charset('utf-8', $connection);` remove the hyphen and try it again.

Comment: Oh damn. Mistyped :(. It already is utf8. But i noticed something different. The sql query i get printed out is only correct if my browsers encoding is set to ISO-8859-1. With UTF-8 it looks horribly wrong.

Comment: Or, after your `$user = new User;` try `$database->query('set name utf8');` or place it before `$result = $database->query($sql);` see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: Is your filed "saved as" UTF8? and this in your document `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: And this is what I use in some of mine `$con->set_charset("utf8");` `$con` being my DB connection variable. Which is placed "before" the query `SELECT * FROM user...`

Comment: Yes my php file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM. And i just exit() my script at the point where it goes wrong, so there is no HTML output. Sadly no luck with $database->query('set name utf8');

Comment: Have you tried my [`other suggestion`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883876/php-mysql-query-no-result-encoding-wrong#comment33137418_21883876) and have you tried it WITH bom?

Comment: The encoding of the file where the link is created was iso-8859-1. Changed it to UTF-8. Now it works. You can create an answer with the tip mentioned above, otherwise i will create my own answer after some days. Thansk a lot!

Comment: That's great news, glad to hear it. And you're very much welcome; I was happy to help. I posted my answer below, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close the question and be marked as solved, and as per [`OP's request`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883876/php-mysql-query-no-result-encoding-wrong?noredirect=1#comment33141203_21883876) including multiple comments to troubleshoot/pinpoint the problem, is to have the file's encoding "saved" as UTF-8 instead of what was presently used "iso-8859-1"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting mysql_set_charset after your database connection

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```